# Phone Locked and safe mode disabled

Tags: recovery-mode, factory-reset, xiaomi

my dad got a new xiaomi mi note 2 and forgot his pattern.So the phone is locked, I tried recovery but the recovery mode is disabled, the same goes for USB debugging.Do you know any way to perform a factory reset?

I read some articles to enter edl mode but i had no success .

Comment: Didn't you get the "sign in with Google account" option after getting the pattern wrong several times?

Comment: To perform hard reset, power off your phone and boot into custom recovery (Power + Volume up key together). From recovery, choose Wipe Data / Factory Reset and confirm the action using Power button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

You have t download the MIFlash Chinese Version

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, your only problem is Lock pattern? Doesn't understand how recovery is locked though - you should be able to simply factory reset device.

I am operating under assumptions that for some unknown reason (not unbelievable in regard to Xiaomi) that you are out of recovery and that bootloader is accessible.

To enter bootloader, press power and volume- buttons simultaneously; a little rabbit with tools and Mao Zedong style hat with communist star should appear.

Before EDL, you should try to enter recovery, after you entered fastboot mode - simply navigate with volume- but confirm with volume+ and do a factory reset.

If this is out of option for you, proceed with entering EDL mode.

First of all, download and install [appropriate drivers for Mi Note 2](http://bigota.d.miui.com/tools/xiaomi_usb_driver.rar).

Second, acquire [MiFlash tool](http://api.bbs.miui.com/url/MiFlash) and stock ROM for [Mi Note 2](http://bigota.d.miui.com/V8.5.5.0.MADMIED/miui_MINote2Global_V8.5.5.0.MADMIED_c600b7af28_6.0.zip) whether it is standard - 4GB/64GB or high - 6GB/128GB edition and extract from archive.

Lobotomized Kenzo && Capricorn models, though eventually restored stock ROM, hence had limited (bad) experience with Xiaomi devices. Extremely frustrating if doing anything outside of box. Had no problems with recent Xiaomi devices, though it's like waiting for rain in London.

If bootloader is accessible and if oem edl or reboot-edl command is present in aboot partition, device can be rebooted to EDL from fastboot with command

```
fastboot oem edl
```

which can be issued on Linux, macOS && Windows platforms (this should be done only on nonVM Windows platform, because you need to flash ROM with MiFlash) or

```
fastboot reboot-edl
```

for which (reboot-edl) you need modified [fastboot](https://androidfilehost.com/?fid=24591000424940129) that can be issued only in Windows (another layer of frustration, because won't work in VM - virtual machine).

If bootloader is unaccessible but oem edl or reboot-edl command is present in aboot partition, you can enter EDL with proper (and timely) button combination for what you need to (exactly in this sequence)

```
Power off device
```

```
Plug USB cable into the station, but without plugging to device
```

```
Press the volume+ and power button while at the same time plugging USB cable to device (timing is critical)
```

```
Device should boot to EDL mode with blinking LED
```

Unfortunately, if none if the above helped you already, you could try with [DIY flash cable](http://en.miui.com/thread-310325-1-1.html) which is substitute for regular USB cable in case bootloader is inaccessible.

In extreme scenario, there is PCB test point method for entering EDL mode, but we need schematics of mainboard for this device, which we don't have at the moment.

Supposing device entered EDL mode, you should start MiFlash which will automatically detect device.

While in MiFlash, click on Browse button, then select Advanced; navigate to directory where you extracted ROM you previously downloaded and optin flashall.bat (not flashall.sh - it is not for Windows platform). Now click on Flash. If everything is correct, it should be finished in couple of minutes.

Device should boot automatically if flash is finished without errors.